# AWS Api Gateway 403 error - CORS enabled from all origins

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a lambda function which is to be accessed via an API Gateway. However whenever a post request is made I get the following error

[image]

When I navigate to was console and look at API Gateway I have

[image]

Finally my code (Angular2) does add the appropriate headers to the request by:

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.post('https://execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/LambdaFunction', this.email, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err));
```

**Any idea how to fix this?**

Comment: You don't need to specify the `Content-Type` header in your Angular code - Angular will take care of this for you. I have even seen cases where removing this from your code has fixed a CORS issue, so try that if you haven't already.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Appreciate the insight though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are beating the wrong bush.

You cannot enable CORS on a 403 since that is sent by APIGateway.
The issue is you are trying to access a URL that is not accessible by APIGateway.

If your URL is correct and POST worked, you will still receive 200 OK on a CORS call, but you will not be able to access the content received. (That is browser standard to avoid CORS call without valid permission on the return headers)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error and I fixed the issue following path:

- Enable CORS options to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" header
  to your response. Dont add authonticater to Options resources.
- Add plugin to web browser to overrride cors settings of browser.
  (just for test on browser. you dont need this while app is running on
  file system)
- check your request url/endpoint to be sure is ok.

Comment: For best practice, if you add these headers to your response, you don't need to apply the second item.

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true

Answer (score -2):

Try this first

1. Enable CORS options to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" header to your response. Dont add authonticater to Options resources.
2. Add plugin to web browser to overrride cors settings of browser. (just for test on browser. you dont need this while app is running on file system)
3. check your request url/endpoint to be sure is ok.

if this is not resolve from above use the below options as well. In my case if resolve by below steps.

1. Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in Default 4XX response. (Refer below Picture.)
2. Redeploy the API.

   [image]

Comment: would like to know why this is down voted. I will keep in mind next time. I thought this will save time for others as it took for me to identify like 30 mins.